# How to automate Chrome Extension with Coded UI?

Tags: .net, automation, coded-ui-tests

I want to fill some data in Chrono Download manager of google chrome through Coded UI script.

I am able to find the button on toolbar to open the extension but not able to get any controls on this extension.

Please suggest how I can access all controls of the extension.

[image]

Some of the sampe code is below:

```
public void FileChromaManagerDownload()
        {

            // this.UIMap.RecordedMethod4();
            // BrowserWindow.CurrentBrowser = "chrome";
            WinWindow window = new WinWindow();

            window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Google - Google Chrome";
            window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Chrome_WidgetWin_1";
            window.WindowTitles.Add("Google - Google Chrome");//This window name may be different as per the website or tab 
            //   window.DrawHighlight();
            //   WinControl uIItemImage = this.UINewTabGoogleChromeWindow.UIChronoDownloadManageButton.UIItemImage;


            WinControl dnBtn = new WinControl(window);
            //  Chrono Download Manager
            // window.SearchProperties.Add(BrowserWindow.PropertyNames.FriendlyName, "Chrono Download Manager");


            dnBtn.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.ControlType, "Button");
            dnBtn.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "Chrono Download Manager");//Chrono Download Manager //Download all resources on this page
            //  dnBtn.DrawHighlight();

            WinControl mUIItemImage = new WinControl(dnBtn);
            mUIItemImage.SearchProperties[UITestControl.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Image";

            //   mUIItemImage.DrawHighlight();
            Playback.Wait(1000);
            Mouse.Click(mUIItemImage);

            window = new WinWindow();



            window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.Name] = "Chrome Legacy Window";
            window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ClassName] = "Chrome_RenderWidgetHostHWND";
            window.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlType] = "Client";
            window.DrawHighlight();
            window.SetFocus();
          //TODO - Now I am not able to fetch any controls of popup windows
        }
```

Comment: What does Coded UI's assertion generation tool show for these controls? Can you record some operations (will need to use Internet Explorer) with Coded UI and generate the code in a sandbox project, then copy the useful pieces into the tests for Chrome?

Comment: @AdrianHHH, I tried to record with Coded UI's but it does not detect any controls. The extension I wanna to automate is not available with IE.

Comment: What does *"not available with IE"* mean? Does the control not work at all when used with IE? Is the control written to only work with Chrome? Should you tell the owners of the website that you have found a mission critical fault: the web site will not work for customers using IE?

Comment: @AdrianHHH The extension "Chrono Downloader Manager" is available only with Chrome.
http://www.chronodownloader.net/

Comment: It may be untestable with Coded UI as it requires the controls to support MSAA or UIA. Coded UI has another interface via IE and another via parts of Selenium, but I think these are basically UIA or MSAA. Try a web search for "Coded UI custom controls" to learn about the challenges of getting applications with custom controls to work with Coded UI - in this context Chrome is just another application, one that has not been written by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Coded UI doesn't support Chrome directly. You have to use some selenium dll in your project and capture the objects in IE then execute them in chrome.

Comment: this extension is not available in chrome.